# Aframe: Changing <a-videosphere> src attribute

Tags: aframe

I am trying to change the src attribute of a videosphere in aframe

```
<a-assets>
<video id="vid" src="videos/vid1.mp4" webkit-playsinline loop></video>
</a-assets>
<a-videosphere src="#vid" rotation="0 180 0"></a-videosphere>
```

I am currently changing the src of the #vid asset using:

```
document.querySelector("#vid").setAttribute("src", "videos/vid2.mp4");
document.quertSelector("a-videosphere").play();
```

However the video remains frozen and the play function returns undefined

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `play` on the `video` element instead of the `video-sphere`:

`document.querySelector("#vid").play();`

What I would do is to have two video elements in `a-assets` and switch the `src` on the `video-sphere` instead of switching the src of a single `video` element

Answer (score 0):

For some material, I have a project that attempts to do video swapping.

Here is a component for playing a video given an event: https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-magicavoxel-projects/blob/master/outsidelands/components/play-video.js

Confirmed that you have to `play` the video element. And perhaps `pause` the current one. I had iterations of the component above pausing other videos, but removed it while trying to debug.

And here is the project in general: https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-magicavoxel-projects/tree/master/outsidelands

I was able to swap video the first time, but had trouble swapping the video a second time.

Comment: hi @ngokevin, if you don't mind can you please chat with me, i need help with aframe videosphere, i know its not the right approach, but please help :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var myVid = document.getElementById("#vid");
$("#myVid").attr("src", "videos/vid2.mp4");
myVid.play();
```

First, you add the source of the video in your assets and then you play it.